# How to store changes of structures in MySQL Database

Tags: mysql

I have a requirement to store the structures of Tables,Stored proc,Views,Events,Triggers if any modification is done.

Is there any plugin (maybe like Tortoise SVN or GIT Repo, not sure) to store the structures when doing the deployments?

Can we do the deployments for MySQL through Tortoise SVN like we do for  MS SQL? Can we do the deployments for MySQL through Jenkins GIT Repo.